# Navigation ul li a detect which is clicked and do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've decided to build my own navigation from scratch.

I am using jquery if/else to handle the interaction.

The issue I am having is detecting which UL LI A is clicked, and then doing something based upon that result (Using $this). I can get the first depth level to function correctly, ie the first UL LI A on-click opens the first sub-child UL with class .c (C = Child), but not the next depth level below that, ie the second UL LI A doesn't open the second sub-child UL with class .sc (SC = Sub Child).

[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/xzabitor/p5pnea7g/1/)

Here is live example:

```js
!function(n){
  $('ul li a + ul').prev('a').append('<span class=ai></span>');
  $('ul li a').on('click', function(n) {
    if($('.c').css('display') == 'none') {
     $this = $(this);
     $(".c").slideToggle();
     $this.find('span.ai').toggleClass('st');
     n.preventDefault();
    } else if($(this).is('ul li.p a')) {
     $this = $(this);
     $(".c").slideToggle();
     $this.find('span.ai').toggleClass('st');
     n.preventDefault();
    } else if ($(this).is('ul li.sp a')) {
     $this = $(this);
     $(".sc").slideToggle();
     $this.find('span.ai').toggleClass('st');
     n.preventDefault();
    }
  });
}(jQuery);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
ul li {
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  background: #c8c8c8;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
}
ul li a {
  display: block;
}
ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
ul li ul li {
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 10px;
}
ul li ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
ul span {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid #000;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul span.st {
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div x-n>
    <ul>
   <li><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
   <li class=p><a href="#" title="About us">About us</a>
    <ul class=c> 
     <li class=sp><a href="#" title="History">History</a>
      <ul class=sc>
       <li>Beginnings</li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#" title="Our team">Our team</a>
     <li><a href="#" title="Our mission statement">Our mission statement</a>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#" title="Clients">Clients</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="Work">Work</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
        </div>
```

Things I have tried:

- Anonymous function
- Using :not operator in reference to $(this) ie, else if($(this).is('ul li.p a:not(ul li.sp a)'))
- Using a integer variable to detect how many clicks based on criteria and then doing something

There's probably a really simple solution here and I'm just not seeing it. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah that would be another term for it. I'll change it now.

Comment: I'm not sure how your code is supposed to work. You've got these hardcoded references to `.c` and `.sc`. I don't see anything that does scoping. I would expect to see something like: when `a` is clicked, find parent `li`, find `ul` in parent `li` and toggle display. Cryptic variable or class names like `p` and `st` also don't help me understand your code.

Comment: Basically I had it so that when any of the ul li a's were clicked, they would get parsed with $(this) and then filtered out with the classes. So if I clicked on the top parent element it'd open the child element, .p click open .c, and if i clicked on the second parent element it'd open the sub-child element, .sp click open .sc.

Comment: Yea that works but you don't need do that since the structure is already in the HTML. Which submenu goes where is implied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems overcomplicated.

Something like this should work

```
  $('ul li a').on('click', function(e) {            
        var $link=$(this), $submenu = $link.siblings('ul');
        if($submenu.length){
            e.preventDefault();
            $link.find('span.ai').toggleClass('st');
            $submenu.slideToggle()
        }        
    });
```

I'm not 100% sure what expected behavior is

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/er3Lhsnn/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
! function(n) {
    $('ul li a + ul').prev('a').append('<span class=ai></span>');
    $('.t').on('click', function(n) {
        $('[x-n]').toggleClass("e");
        n.preventDefault();
    });
    $('ul li a').on('click', function(n) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('st')) {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
            $(this).addClass('st');
            $(this).find('span.ai').toggleClass('st');
        } else {
            $(this).next().slideUp();
            $(this).removeClass('st');
            $(this).find('span.ai').toggleClass('st');
        }
    });
}(jQuery);
```